# Trying to sort multiindex index using categorical index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a `MultiIndexed` dataframe like below

```py
months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : np.arange(1,25,1)},\
                  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months, [1,2]], names = ['idx_1', 'idx_2'])).sort_index()

print(df)

                 col
idx_1     idx_2     
April     1        7
          2        8
August    1       15
          2       16
December  1       23
          2       24
February  1        3
          2        4
January   1        1
          2        2
July      1       13
          2       14
June      1       11
          2       12
March     1        5
          2        6
May       1        9
          2       10
November  1       21
          2       22
October   1       19
          2       20
September 1       17
          2       18
```

I wanted to `sort the index` so I created a `CategoricalIndex` and assigned it to the level_0 of the MultiIndex. However, even after that the sort command doesn't sort the index.

```py
cidx = pd.CategoricalIndex(data = df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), categories = months, ordered=True)
df.index = df.index.set_levels(cidx, level = 0)
df = df.sort_index(level = 0)
print(df)
```

It will produce the same output as above. I think it's a `bug`. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the level_0 of the MultiIndex

```
print(df.index.get_level_values(0))

CategoricalIndex(['April', 'April', 'August', 'August', 'December', 'December',
                  'February', 'February', 'January', 'January', 'July', 'July',
                  'June', 'June', 'March', 'March', 'May', 'May', 'November',
                  'November', 'October', 'October', 'September', 'September'],
                 categories=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', ...], ordered=True, dtype='category', name='idx_1')
```

Comment: Seems like a bug. Probably because it's inside a multiindex, right? As a single index it sorts correctly.  Is this bug specific to `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`, does it happen without it?

Comment: @creanion, in reality I import data from a collection of csv files (one for each month) and concat them with keys as month names, I created a lookalike using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`. I am thinking of reporting this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I must say that this problem is a Pandas bug.

In this problem the Dataframe has been sorted after it has been created. Using sort command like `sort_index()` in earlier steps causes Pandas to have sorting problems. Categorical index sorting fails with lexicographically ordered multi-indexed data.
Several tricks can be used to solve this problem in these cases.

1. Avoid using commands that sort the index lexicographically. lexicographically ordered data cannot be sorted using a categorical index.
2. You can first reset the desired index level using `reset_index()`. Then you can make a `CategoricalIndex` and use it to categorize the column.

   ```
   months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
             'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']    
   df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(1, 25, 1)},
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months, [1, 2]], names=['idx_1', 'idx_2'])).sort_index()


   df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

   df['idx_1'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['idx_1'], months,  ordered=True)

   df.set_index('idx_1', append=True, inplace=True)

   df.swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index(level=0)
   ```
3. You can first create a `CategoricalIndex` and assign it to the level_0 of the MultiIndex. Afterward, you need to eliminate the lexicographical sort from the zero-level index. You can use two consecutive `sort_index()` here as a trick.

   ```
   months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

   df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(1, 25, 1)},
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months, [1, 2]], names=['idx_1', 'idx_2'])).sort_index()

   categories = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.levels[0], categories=months, ordered=True)

   df.index = df.index.set_levels(categories, level=0)

   df.sort_index(level=1).sort_index(level=0)
   ```

output:

```
                 col
idx_1     idx_2     
January   1        1
          2        2
February  1        3
          2        4
March     1        5
          2        6
April     1        7
          2        8
May       1        9
          2       10
June      1       11
          2       12
July      1       13
          2       14
August    1       15
          2       16
September 1       17
          2       18
October   1       19
          2       20
November  1       21
          2       22
December  1       23
          2       24
```

---

Since, it's actually a bug, updates can be seen on [repo here.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47607)

Comment: I had three doubts:

1) Could you explain what _earlier steps_ in _Using sort command like sort_index() in earlier steps_ mean?

2)  You say _Categorical index sorting fails with lexicographically ordered data_. But my code works fine for a non-multindexed dataframe(with just months as index). So, it seems wrong.

3) Could explain how you trick works in the third point? It's cool though.

Comment: @Dhruv, First, I must say that this problem is a Pandas bug. The things mentioned are from my experience working with CategoricalIndexes. 
About your comments: 1) My experience has shown that this problem occurs when an index (in multiindex dataframe or series) has been sorted before changing the type of an index to categorical. In your example, this sorting is done with `sort_index()` right after defining the dataframe. In some cases, this sorting may be done by commands such as `groupby()` that have the Sort argument. 2) This bug occurs when the dataframe or series is multiindex.

Comment: @Dhruv  
3) As mentioned, if the desired index is sorted lexicographically before changing the type to categorical, the mentioned bug will occur. When `sort_index(level=1)` is used first, the order of the desired index (level_0) will no longer be lexicographical. So, as mentioned, this time by sorting it with sort_index(level=0) you can get the desired result. Again, it should be noted that this is a bug. The solutions are based on previous experiences in working with categorical multiindex dataframes and are not an official technique.

Comment: Why didn't you accept the edits? The statement `Categorical index sorting fails with lexicographically ordered data` is incorrect until you specify index is `multi-index`. Also, I have reported this bug [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47607). It would be nice to add this to the answer as well.

Comment: Hello @Dhruv.

I live in Iran, and as you probably know, the Iranian dictatorial regime severely suppresses the Internet in Iran. Today I barely got access to the internet. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Here are two other workarounds for custom sorting an index that don't rely on `pd.CategoricalIndex`:

#### Using `reindex`

You can apply a custom order by reindexing the relevant level:

```py
months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
]

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months, [1, 2]], names = ['idx_1', 'idx_2'])
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        data = range(1,25),
        columns = ['col'],
        index = mi
    )
    .reindex(months, level=0)
)
df
```

#### Using sorting key in `sort_index`

We can map the index to a custom sort order by utilizing the `key` argument of `sort_index` :

```py
months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
]

mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([months, [1, 2]], names = ['idx_1', 'idx_2'])
sorter = lambda idx: idx.map({n:m for m,n in enumerate(months)})
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        data = range(1,25),
        columns = ['col'],
        index = mi
    )
    .sort_index(level=0, key=sorter)
)
df
```